# Moving from Wired-to-Wifi causes downstream network port to get disabled?

Tags: home-networking

When I move my MacBook Pro from Wired to Wireless Connectivity -  the Vio Router disables the port-facing the Airport Extreme until I physically bounce the Hub. Any ideas what this could be?

All of my houses personal devices are behind an Airport Express in bridging mode. There is a weird quirk that I do not know how to fix:

```
Airport Express -> Airport Extreme -> Vios Router -> Cable Modem
                   ^
Wired Hub ---------|
```

Both the Airport Express and Wired Hub have several devices plugged in (raspberry) or connected (iphones etc).

Comment: This is a guess, but it sounds like some kind of anti-mac address spoofing is kicking in when it sees your macbook's moved to a different port. You'd need to look at your routers config and logs (if it has any) to try and work out exactly what's happening.

Comment: Well that's the thing - if they are connected at the same-time, it's fine. It's only when I am on WiFi but not Wired that it acts up...

Comment: I was able to replicate this finally. It looks like the HYPER usb hub / network adapter is triggering this, how / why I do not know ...